# Access Session in Class using .Net Core 3.1 Razor Pages Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, razor-pages

I wish to check various session values from within my custom class.  One thing I want to test is if the LoggedIn variable is set when a user hits a specific page.  I want to do this in a class so I don't have to repeat code.

Here is how I've registered the service / IHttpContextAccessor:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddScoped<clsSessionHelper>();

        services.AddRazorPages();
        
        services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/App/Mpl/MplHome/MplHome", "");
        });

        services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1200);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });          
        // End Session Support

        services.AddMemoryCache();
                   
    }
```

Here is how I've build the custom class:

```
public class clsSessionHelper
{

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public clsSessionHelper(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
    }

    public string getValue(string SessionKey)
    {

        string strResult =  _session.GetString(SessionKey);

        return strResult;

    }
```

When I try to use the my helper class in a xx.cshtml.cs file like be below

```
clsSessionHelper objSessionHelper = new clsSessionHelper();                
Test = objSessionHelper.getValue("LoggedIn");
```

I get an intellsense error "there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'httpContextAccessor' of 'clsSessionHelper.clsSessionHelper(HttpContextAccessor)'.

No doubt, I'm messing up the dependency injection.  Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Can't see why it doesn't work, but anyway you can also add it using `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()`

Comment: Your text says "[...]formal parameter 'httpContextAccessor' of 'clsSessionHelper.clsSessionHelper(HttpContextAccessor)'". Either that one is copypasted, or the code, but not both. Maybe your ctor actually has (HttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) instead of the interface type?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that at the time the custom class is initialized and the `IHttpContextAccessor`  injected, it is too early in the request process to have access to the `HttpContext` and by extension the `ISession`

Move any code that depend on the `HttpContext` out of the construct and into a member that is invoked during the context of a request.

```
public class clsSessionHelper : ISessionHelper {

    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;        

    public clsSessionHelper(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;        
    }

    public string getValue(string SessionKey) {
        ISession session = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
        string strResult =  session.GetString(SessionKey);
        return strResult;    
    }
}
```

Also abstract your custom class

```
public interface ISessionHelper  {
    string getValue(string SessionKey);
}
```

so it too can be injected where needed.

```
//...

services.AddScoped<ISessionHelper, clsSessionHelper>();

//...
```

Avoid trying to initialize it manually.

```
private readonly ISessionHelper objSessionHelper;                

public MyPageModel(ISessionHelper objSessionHelper) {
    this.objSessionHelper = objSessionHelper;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet() {
    var Test = objSessionHelper.getValue("LoggedIn");

    //...
}
```